# How to convert y_true and y_pred from tensorflow 2 into numpy array?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to write a custom loss function to use in a Tensorflow 2 model.
def loss(y_true, y_pred):
1. wish to convert y_true and y_pred to numpy array (these are images)
2. After that I wish to carry out some operations (such as binarization of images, some pixel wise AND
or OR operation etc.)
3. Finally get a single floating number as a loss, and feed it to the model and minimize the loss.

can any one please suggest me how to do it? I already tried many of the options given on the internet but I am not able to convert y_true and y_pred into a numpy array.

Comment: You haven't told us anything about what data type you have.

Comment: Hi Brian, Actually I am doing it for semantic segmentation. The data type is image. I wish to minimize segmentation loss of prediction with ground truth using dice coefficient. In tensorflow 2, I saw there are ways to define the dice loss using tensorflow (https://lars76.github.io/2018/09/27/loss-functions-for-segmentation.html). I would like at first to convert tensors to numpy array.  .

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything about the data.  You want to convert your image data of some data type to a numpy array. An image is not a data type.  For example, maybe you loaded a jpeg using Pillow.  In that case you can convert it to a numpy array using "data = asarray(image)".  Maybe you are using OpenCV.  We don't know.  Add some code that shows where the image came from and run "print type(yourImage)" and add the result to your post.

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66039301/tensorflow-custom-loss-valueerror-no-gradients-provided-for-any-variable/66039723#66039723 help ?

Comment: Hi @Andrey, Thanks for the suggestion, I understood the problem of the link between numpy and Tensorflow. can you please tell me if there is anyway to deal with it? or to write custom loss or any other modification, the option is only to play with Tensorflow and keras libraries.

Comment: @Param check Numpy API: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tf_numpy

Comment: @Andrey , Thanks a lot. I will go through it.